# Example of subgroup of the automorphism group

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

Let $A(G) := \{α ∈ Aut(G) \mid ∀U ≤ G. α(U) = U\}$.

I had to prove that $A(G)$ is A subgroup of $Aut(G)$ and that it's normal in it.

Now I need to find a group $G$ such that $A(G) \neq \{id_G\}$.
I though of an example but I'm not sure in it: $G = \{e,a,a^2\}$. However, I could not find any $f\in A(G)$. 
Any help?

Comment: Notational hint: Use backslashes to make the curly braces appear: `\{\}` makes $\{\}$.

Comment: By $∀U ≤ G$, do you mean "for all subgroups $U$ of $G$"?

Comment: Your example is good. To find a non-trivial automorphism, consider what happens when you switch the two non-identity elements.

Comment: @Arthur - yes, I mean for all subgroup $U$ in $G$

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft $f(g) = g^4$ is a good example? it is not considered to be $id_G$?

Comment: Sure, or just $g\mapsto g^2$, which is the same map.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft but in you example if $U=${$e,a$} than $a^2$ is not in $U$

Comment: But that is not a subgroup.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that $g\mapsto g^2$ and $g\mapsto g^4$ of course are not the same map. The second one is the identity.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft You are right. The only subgroup of $G = ${$e,a,a^2$} is G itself, right?

Comment: Well, that and the trivial subgroup $\{e\}$. But yes, those are the only ones.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks!!